# PHP unix timestamp to UTC zend framework

Tags: php, datetime, cookies, timestamp, session-cookies

Ok, this may be a simple question, maybe I am thinking about this all wrong. Who knows.

Anyway, I am using Zend Framework and I am attempting to use cookies for the first time in it. So from my understanding cookies in Zend use a format like:

> Wednesday, 28-Feb-05 20:41:22 UTC

for the expires. So I am trying to figure out how to take `time()` and convert it to a similar `date()` variation of the above that is 2 hours in the future and UTC. But like I said I think I am over thinking it, so I need confirmation.

My thoughts is

```
$cookie_expire = time()+7200;
$cookie_expire = date('l, d-M-y H:i:s Z', $cookie_expire);
```

And I wanna say this is correct, however something in my head doesn't sit well with the notion so, hopefully someone can tell me if I am off on the idea or not.

Comment: Have you tried? What was the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.gmdate.php

See the comment by Glen @ 4-Dec-2007 04:32:

```
This routine can help obtain a UTC timestamp:

<?php
$utc_str = gmdate("M d Y H:i:s", time());
$utc = strtotime($utc_str);
?>
```

Replace the `time()` with the timestamp you want to convert.